# Using lambda functions in groupby.agg, pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({
'animal': ['dog', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat'],
'color': ['brown', 'black', 'white', 'black', 'black']})
```

I am trying to write a groupby function like this:

```
groupby('animal').agg(
proportion_of_black=('color', lambda x: 1 if x == 'black' else 0)).reset_index()
```

It returns the following error message:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Where is my code going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your question asks for proportion and not counts, you should do:

```
df.groupby(['animal']).agg(
   proportion=('color', lambda x: x.eq('black').mean())).reset_index()

    animal  proportion
0   cat     0.500000
1   dog     0.666667
```

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny There's no numeric data, and it's not a mean.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Henry is correct. mean is the proportion of logical values

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny also Henry's solution is the best in this scenario.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny yes. Because mean is the short form of sum/count

Comment: I guess we have different interpretation on what it meant by "one function call" :)

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code with `any`

```
df.groupby('animal').agg(
proportion_of_black=('color', lambda x: 1 if any(x == 'black') else 0)).reset_index()
```

If need the count of black

```
df.groupby('animal').agg(
proportion_of_black=('color', lambda x: sum(x == 'black') )).reset_index()
Out[124]: 
  animal  proportion_of_black
0    cat                    1
1    dog                    2
```

Update 2

```
pd.crosstab(df.animal,df.color,normalize='index') # ['black']
Out[128]: 
color      black     brown  white
animal                           
cat     0.500000  0.000000    0.5
dog     0.666667  0.333333    0.0
```

Comment: I am looking to aggregate a count of 'black'. Not specify if any of them are black.

Comment: Thank you so much @BEN_YO ! Now what if I want a percentage of black within each animal? So dog would be 0.66 for black and cat would be .5 for black?

Comment: @MichaelMathewsJr. check the update again, also , please post your all question in one time, if not you will received some downvote in the future

Comment: Ok I'm sorry will not do that in the future

Comment: This here is the best way to approach this kind of problem

Answer (score 2):

**Where is my code going wrong?** When you do:

```
df.groupby('animal').agg(
proportion_of_black=('color', lambda x: 1 if x == 'black' else 0))
```

`x` is the series `color` for each animals, e.g. `df.loc[df['animal']=='dog', 'color']`. So `x=='black'` is a series of boolean. However `if` in Python only accept a single boolean. And Pandas doesn't know how to convert the series `x==black` to a single boolean to pass to `if x=='black`, and it complains as you see.

**How to fix your code**: `apply` should be avoided, even after `groupby()`. In your case, you can get the propotion of black with `mean()`:

```
df['color'].eq('black').groupby(df['animal']).mean()
```

Output:

```
animal
cat    0.500000
dog    0.666667
Name: color, dtype: float64
```